# How to create a "normal" color image from multiband RGB images with GDAL CLI?

Tags: gdal, sentinel-2, bash

I am working on a personal project to automatically pull and process Sentinel 2 data and create viewable images with a bash script. So far I have succeesded with most of the steps but I'm stuck at the last and most important task: Creating a "normal" image. I don't know the correct English word for what I want to create which is probably while my Google searches failed.
I do have a 3 banded GeoTIFF/GeoPNG image which structurally looks fine to me so far. Each band has the correct color channel assigned. What I want to create is a PNG image which displays as a color image in any image viewer or web browser. The multiband image appears just as grayscale in an image viewer or web browser but looks fine in QGIS.
If somebody could please tell me how those two image types are called correctly in English and how to create one that displays correctly outside of GIS software.

gdalinfo for my composite:

```
Driver: PNG/Portable Network Graphics
Files: TCI.png
       TCI.png.aux.xml
Size is 2716, 2732
Coordinate System is:
PROJCRS["WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator",
    BASEGEOGCRS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
            ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        ID["EPSG",4326]],
    CONVERSION["unnamed",
        METHOD["Popular Visualisation Pseudo Mercator",
            ID["EPSG",1024]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8801]],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8802]],
        PARAMETER["False easting",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8806]],
        PARAMETER["False northing",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8807]]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["(E)",east,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
        AXIS["(N)",north,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
    ID["EPSG",3857]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 1,2
Origin = (2649142.836674000602216,8705200.525860572233796)
Pixel Size = (20.472334733741381,-20.475878685556005)
Metadata:
  AOT_QUANTIFICATION_VALUE=1000.0
  AOT_QUANTIFICATION_VALUE_UNIT=none
  AOT_RETRIEVAL_ACCURACY=0.0
  AOT_RETRIEVAL_METHOD=CAMS
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  BOA_QUANTIFICATION_VALUE=10000
  BOA_QUANTIFICATION_VALUE_UNIT=none
  CLOUDY_PIXEL_OVER_LAND_PERCENTAGE=2.178992
  CLOUD_COVERAGE_ASSESSMENT=3.821333
  CLOUD_SHADOW_PERCENTAGE=0.199545
  DARK_FEATURES_PERCENTAGE=0.010956
  DATATAKE_1_DATATAKE_SENSING_START=2022-02-11T09:51:31.024Z
  DATATAKE_1_DATATAKE_TYPE=INS-NOBS
  DATATAKE_1_ID=GS2A_20220211T095131_034682_N04.00
  DATATAKE_1_SENSING_ORBIT_DIRECTION=DESCENDING
  DATATAKE_1_SENSING_ORBIT_NUMBER=79
  DATATAKE_1_SPACECRAFT_NAME=Sentinel-2A
  DEGRADED_ANC_DATA_PERCENTAGE=0.0
  DEGRADED_MSI_DATA_PERCENTAGE=0
  FORMAT_CORRECTNESS=PASSED
  GENERAL_QUALITY=PASSED
  GENERATION_TIME=2022-02-11T10:36:49.000000Z
  GEOMETRIC_QUALITY=PASSED
  GRANULE_MEAN_AOT=0.059267
  GRANULE_MEAN_WV=0.576791
  HIGH_PROBA_CLOUDS_PERCENTAGE=0.393576
  L2A_QUALITY=PASSED
  MEDIUM_PROBA_CLOUDS_PERCENTAGE=3.396076
  NODATA_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE=6.6E-5
  NOT_VEGETATED_PERCENTAGE=26.093891
  OZONE_SOURCE=AUX_ECMWFT
  OZONE_VALUE=385.595992
  PREVIEW_GEO_INFO=Not applicable
  PREVIEW_IMAGE_URL=Not applicable
  PROCESSING_BASELINE=04.00
  PROCESSING_LEVEL=Level-2A
  PRODUCT_DOI=https://doi.org/10.5270/S2_-znk9xsj
  PRODUCT_START_TIME=2022-02-11T09:51:31.024Z
  PRODUCT_STOP_TIME=2022-02-11T09:51:31.024Z
  PRODUCT_TYPE=S2MSI2A
  PRODUCT_URI=S2A_MSIL2A_20220211T095131_N0400_R079_T34VFN_20220211T103649.SAFE
  RADIATIVE_TRANSFER_ACCURACY=0.0
  RADIOMETRIC_QUALITY=PASSED
  REFLECTANCE_CONVERSION_U=1.02808919156049
  SATURATED_DEFECTIVE_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE=0.0
  SENSOR_QUALITY=PASSED
  SNOW_ICE_PERCENTAGE=68.545651
  SPECIAL_VALUE_NODATA=0
  SPECIAL_VALUE_SATURATED=65535
  THIN_CIRRUS_PERCENTAGE=0.031682
  UNCLASSIFIED_PERCENTAGE=0.190856
  VEGETATION_PERCENTAGE=0.101055
  WATER_PERCENTAGE=1.036713
  WATER_VAPOUR_RETRIEVAL_ACCURACY=0.0
  WVP_QUANTIFICATION_VALUE=1000.0
  WVP_QUANTIFICATION_VALUE_UNIT=cm
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  ( 2649142.837, 8705200.526) ( 23d47'51.56"E, 61d20'37.76"N)
Lower Left  ( 2649142.837, 8649260.425) ( 23d47'51.56"E, 61d 6' 6.87"N)
Upper Right ( 2704745.698, 8705200.526) ( 24d17'49.72"E, 61d20'37.76"N)
Lower Right ( 2704745.698, 8649260.425) ( 24d17'49.72"E, 61d 6' 6.87"N)
Center      ( 2676944.267, 8677230.476) ( 24d 2'50.64"E, 61d13'23.15"N)
Band 1 Block=2716x1 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Red
  Description = B4, central wavelength 665 nm
  Metadata:
    BANDNAME=B4
    BANDWIDTH=30
    BANDWIDTH_UNIT=nm
    SOLAR_IRRADIANCE=1512.06
    SOLAR_IRRADIANCE_UNIT=W/m2/um
    WAVELENGTH=665
    WAVELENGTH_UNIT=nm
Band 2 Block=2716x1 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Green
  Description = B3, central wavelength 560 nm
  Metadata:
    BANDNAME=B3
    BANDWIDTH=35
    BANDWIDTH_UNIT=nm
    SOLAR_IRRADIANCE=1823.24
    SOLAR_IRRADIANCE_UNIT=W/m2/um
    WAVELENGTH=560
    WAVELENGTH_UNIT=nm
Band 3 Block=2716x1 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Blue
  Description = B2, central wavelength 490 nm
  Metadata:
    BANDNAME=B2
    BANDWIDTH=65
    BANDWIDTH_UNIT=nm
    SOLAR_IRRADIANCE=1959.66
    SOLAR_IRRADIANCE_UNIT=W/m2/um
    WAVELENGTH=490
    WAVELENGTH_UNIT=nm
```

Screenshot from QGIS:
[image: screenshot from QGIS]

Screenshot from image viewer:
[image: Screenshot from image viewer]

My process:

```
gdal_translate -b 1 -b 2 -b 3 SENTINEL2_L2A:S2A_MSIL2A_20220211T095131_N0400_R079_T34VFN_20220211T103649.SAFE/MTD_MSIL2A.xml:10m:EPSG_32634 TCI_composite.tif
gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:3857 -te_srs EPSG:4326 -te 23.797655 61.101908 24.297144 61.343821 TCI_composite.tif TCI_composite_cropped.tif
gdal_translate TCI_composite_cropped.tif TCI.png
```